# Displaying Images PHP table Mysql

Tags: php

I am trying to display an image, in a table,   the image is in the images folder and the link is placed in the Mysql DB.

This is the line of code that calls the image.  The mysql query is working but it is only displaying the image link as text and not the picture.

```
<tr ><td >Image</td>

<td ><input type=text name=image value='<img src="<?echo $row['image'];?>"'></td></tr>
```

I am new to PHP and Mysql, i'm just stuck at this piece of code,

How do i get the image to display in the table and not just the code.

thanks

Comment: Why would you use the `input`-tag here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use an `<input>` tag here, just the `<img>` tag:

```
<tr><td>Image</td>

<td><img src="<?echo $row['image'];?>"></td></tr>
```

This presumes that the link in your DB contains the path to your image and not just the image name.
Eg:

```
$row['image'] = /path/to/image.format
```